# What is a shaved polygon?

Tags: terminology

Just trying to find a definition.

I was asked this in an interview and I assumed it was a polygon created by incorrectly modifying a another polygon in a coverage.

According to my best googling resulting in this code: http://www.falconview.org/svn/FalconView/trunk/public/fvw_core/Utility/GeometryUtils.cpp and my limited understanding of it.  A shaved polygon occurs when you eliminate a polygon and your surface no longer forms a convex hull.  I would assume this is important in a situation where keeping area constant (such as city limits).

Comment: When the polygons overlap they create slivers, in ArcGIS the Eliminate Tool would remove them.

Comment: (+1) This is not a well-known term, nor does it appear to have a consistent definition. See (for instance) the definition in the book at http://books.google.com/books?id=GV1JY5KYqxQC&pg=PA85&lpg=PA85&dq=shaved+polygon&source=bl&ots=a_xsqO8x8n&sig=D4FAqILg8H_MU_qYC6eUZGJ08O4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=oTQdUbaMNcHo0gHBj4DYAw&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=shaved%20polygon&f=false. In such an interview I would just have admitted my ignorance and perhaps commented on the need in GIS to be careful about our terms (and not assume everyone has a common understanding).

Comment: People ask stupid questions in interviews sometimes. An esoteric technical detail has no value for determining ability or knowledge -- but it's not even a technical detail if google gives 1 result for "shaved polygon", and it's a random code comment. Probably meant a polygon sliver via Mapperz... See worst interview question on Earth: “What’s the difference between varchar and varchar2 in Oracle 8i?” http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/GuerrillaInterviewing3.html

Comment: Were you interviewing for a job that requires familiarity with data used by Falconview?

Comment: I am afraid not